# Upgrade database from SQL Server 2000 to 2005 -- and rebuild full-text indexes?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, recovery

I'm loading a ***SQL Server 2000*** database into my new ***SQL Server 2005*** ***instance***. ***As expected, the full-text catalogs don't come with it.*** **How can I rebuild them?**

Right-clicking my full text catalogs and hitting "***rebuild indexes***" just hangs for hours and hours without doing anything, so it doesn't appear to be that simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using SQL.

- [CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189520%28SQL.90%29.aspx)
- [ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176095%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Here's an example from Microsoft.

```
--Change to accent insensitive
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG ftCatalog 
REBUILD WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY=OFF;
GO
-- Check Accentsensitivity
SELECT FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY('ftCatalog', 'accentsensitivity');
GO
--Returned 0, which means the catalog is not accent sensitive.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that helped because it showed what was wrong: My file paths were different. Here's how I fixed it:

1) Load database from SQL 2000 backup

2) Set compatibility mode to SQL 2005

```
USE mydb
GO

ALTER DATABASE mydb SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
GO
```

3) Get the filegroup names

```
SELECT name 
  FROM sys.master_files mf 
 WHERE type = 4 
   AND EXISTS( SELECT * 
                 FROM sys.databases db 
                WHERE db.database_id = mf.database_id 
                  AND name           = 'mydb')
```

4) Then for each name (I did this in a little script)

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb 
MODIFY FILE( NAME = {full text catalog name}, FILENAME="N:\ew\path\to\wherever")
```

5) Then collect all the "readable" names of the catalogs:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.sysfulltextcatalogs
```

6) Finally, now you can rebuild each one:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG {full text catalog name} REBUILD
```